# attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference android studio using wowza

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, wowza

I am trying to start a broadcast using wowza. I am using a sample application that when I compile works perfectly.

However when I try to use this in my own project I get this error when I try to start the broadcast:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.caper.teststream, PID: 26004
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.wowza.gocoder.sdk.api.broadcast.WOWZBroadcastConfig.setStreamName(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at com.caper.teststream.WowzaCamera.start(WowzaCamera.java:80)
    at com.caper.teststream.BroadcastActivity.onClick(BroadcastActivity.java:59)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6891)
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:12651)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26083)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

also the camera does not display in the preview

here is my code

```
public class BroadcastActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements  View.OnClickListener {

WOWZCameraView mWowzaPreview;
WowzaCamera mWowza = null;
boolean mIsBroadcastStarted = false;

private boolean mPermissionsGranted = true;
private static int mPermissionCount = 0;
private String[] mRequiredPermissions = new String[]{
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
        Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
};
private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WOWZA = 367;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_broadcast);

    // Don't turn off screen while in this activity
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    mWowzaPreview =  findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);

    Button broadcastBtn = findViewById(R.id.broadcast_button);
    broadcastBtn.setOnClickListener(this);


}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Button btn = (Button)view;

    if(!mIsBroadcastStarted)
    {

        // Name of stream is assigned here
        mWowza.start("myStream2");
        mIsBroadcastStarted = true;
        btn.setText("STOP");
    } else {
        mWowza.stop();
        btn.setText("START");
        mIsBroadcastStarted = false;
    }



}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    //Check appropriate permissions
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        mPermissionsGranted = hasPermissions(this, mRequiredPermissions);
        if (!mPermissionsGranted)
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, mRequiredPermissions, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WOWZA);
        else {
            initializeWowzaCamera();
        }
    } else {
        mPermissionsGranted = true;
        initializeWowzaCamera();
    }
}

private boolean isInit = false;

private void initializeWowzaCamera(){
    if (!isInit) {
        mWowza = new WowzaCamera(BroadcastActivity.this, mWowzaPreview);
        isInit = true;

    }
    if (mWowza != null) {
        mWowza.onResume();
        mWowzaPreview.onResume();

    }
}

private static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String[] permissions) {
    for (String permission : permissions)
        if (context.checkCallingOrSelfPermission(permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            return false;

    return true;
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WOWZA: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            // Check the result of each permission granted

            mPermissionCount++;

            for (int grantResult : grantResults) {
                if (grantResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                    mPermissionsGranted = false;
                }
            }

            if (mPermissionsGranted && mPermissionCount == 3) {
                initializeWowzaCamera();
            }


            if (!mPermissionsGranted && mPermissionCount == 3) {
                mPermissionCount = 0;
                finish();
            }

            return;
        }
    }
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if(mWowza!=null)
    mWowza.onPause();
    super.onPause();
}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    mWowza.stop();
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

please help

Comment: working app sample  http://capertv.com/download/WowzaSample.zip  not working http://capertv.com/download/testStream.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you aren't calling initializeWowzaCamera() when checking if permissions have been granted. Do you mean?

```
if (mPermissionsGranted && grantResults.length == 3) {
    initializeWowzaCamera();
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for getting back to me am not to familiar with this however i can send a link to the sample app and my project app if you want to have a try @Richard Stokes

Comment: You can search for the line "if (mPermissionsGranted && mPermissionCount == 3)" and replace it with the above code

Comment: i tried but no joy here is the sours code for both working app sample  http://capertv.com/download/WowzaSample.zip  not working http://capertv.com/download/testStream.zip

Comment: Check your SDK key / GOCODER key is valid? It says it isn't valid for this application. You'll need to register again for your application id 
"com.caper.teststream" https://www.wowza.com/products/gocoder/sdk/license